# want to change background color of image on onmouseEnte in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i want to change my background color of image on when mouser enter on image and chnge color when it leave here is my code

```
changecolor(e)
{  e.preventDefault();
this.setState({color:'#FF0000'});
console.log('color',this.state.color);
}

resetcolor(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({color:'yellow'});
console.log('color',this.state.color);
}
```

here is my jsx code

```
          {this.state.images.map((items) => <img src={items.media.m}
           onMouseEnter={ this.changecolor.bind(this)}onMouseLeave={this.resetImage.bind(this)} 
           style={{maxWidth:'30vh',maxHeight:'70vh',backgroundColor:this.state.color}} />)}
```

Comment: I'm pretty much sure you can achieve this with css

Comment: i totally agree with @SergeySklyar

Comment: how i dont know the syntax???????